# How to escape pipe character ('|') in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, import, special-characters, postgresql-9.5

So I'm trying to import series of pipe delimited files into PgAdmin III (utilizing a PostgreSQL 9.5 DB).

I ended up getting the error:

```
ERROR: extra data after last expected column
SQL state: 22P04
```

Basically the line had 25 columns where there should have been 17... Why? Well I figured out there were pipe ("|") characters in a couple of the fields.

I'm using the following command to import:

```
START TRANSACTION;
copy drugs FROM 'path/to/source_file.rrf' (DELIMITER '|', FORMAT TEXT);
COMMIT;
```

I had been referring to the lexical structure [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html), although I might have been doing it wrong...

I've already tried replacing the pipe characters in fields with '/|' and '//|', but so far, both result in the same error message as above.

Thanks so much and let me know if you need more information!

Comment: Can you show us some examples of "bad" data?

Comment: This is an example field: `VX-703 is an anti-cytokine therapy in which p38 MAP kinase inhibitor effectively inhibits LPS-stimulated TNF|[alpha]|, IL-6 and IL-1|[beta]| production.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need quote the whole column value to use a delimiter as a part of field data. For example:

```
filed_one|field_two|with_a_delimiter_inside|field_three
```

Should be transformed to

```
filed_one|"field_two|with_a_delimiter_inside"|field_three
```

or

```
"filed_one"|"field_two|with_a_delimiter_inside"|"field_three"
```

Other option is to use backslash to escape delimiter character. Example:

```
filed_one|field_two\|with_a_delimiter_inside|field_three
```

You can find details in the [manual on COPY command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html)

Comment: Your last answer, with the single "\" added up working. I figured out that my Python code was accidentally picking up a match with "|" twice and instead of making it "\|" it was making it "\\|". Many thanks!